# Responsive PDF using Overleaf/LTEX

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

[image]

All i want is to make Table of content responsive like if i click on any section it will take me there. Same is the case for references.
Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Have you tried `\usepackage{hyperref}`?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solven in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597517/responsive-pdf-using-overleaf-ltex/597680#comments-597517) by [Phelype Oleinik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134574/phelype-oleinik), this can be achieved by using the `hyperref` package.